# Android Xml Parsing "embedded values"

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

Im having a hard time trying to figure out how to parse this block of data:

```
<prov version="1.1">
  <characteristic type="section1">
    <parm name="version" value="74"/>
    <parm name="validity" value="172800"/>
  </characteristic>
...
  <characteristic type="section99">
    <parm name="random_setting1" value="blahblah1"/>
    <parm name="random_setting2" value="blahblah2"/>
    <characteristic type="section99_subsection2">
      <parm name="random_setting3" value="blahblah1"/>
      <parm name="random_setting4" value="blahblah2"/>
    </characteristic> 
  </characteristic>
</prov>
```

I have probably 200+ lines in an xml file resembling the above example.  Id like to break it up into 4 fields to put in a database:

1stlevel characteristic

2ndlevel characteristic (can be null)

settingName

value

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I have this document builder:

```
        Log.d("RNM", "Starting xmlToDb");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlParse = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
        xmlParse.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = xmlParse.getElementsByTagName("characteristic");
        for ( int tmp = 0; tmp < nList.getLength(); tmp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(tmp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if ( nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                String charType = eElement.getAttribute("type"); //Tells me the value of characteristic
            }
        }
```

The above works to pull out all the characteristic blocks and can get the values.  but I can't figure out how to extract the parmName and parmValud that lie beneath each one.

Any examples out there on dealing with this?  I looked here:  http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-tutorial/  But I could not figure out how to grab those values with the saxparser.

Comment: Rieekan, That got me on the right track,  what is missing though is to get the values of the "embedded entries" (not sure what they are called) is xpp.getAttributeCount,  then loop through that number with getAttributeValue to build my dbstring.  next and nextToken help to move along when I get the values i need of each characteristic section from my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Android's [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).

> There are two key methods: next() and nextToken(). While next() provides access to high level parsing events, nextToken() allows access to lower level tokens.

An example usage:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

public class SimpleXmlPullApp
{
     public static void main (String args[])
         throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
     {
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
         System.out.println("End document");
     }
}
```