# Disecting response from server to get what you need

Tags: java, android, get, httpurlconnection, httpresponse

Hi I am successfully retrieving data from my database using a GET request.

In my database I have 3 fields - `employeeId, employeeName, userPin`.

However, from my android app when I get the response message I would only like to see the `userPin`.

Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:7001/engAppApi/webservices/usersTable/"+ id;

            URL object = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +token);
            con.setRequestProperty
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            Log.d("responsecode", String.valueOf(con.getResponseCode()));
            Log.d("responsemessage", String.valueOf(con.getHeaderFields()));

            if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK || con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED ) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    userPinRetrieved+=line;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ErrorAPP", e.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

POSTMAN RESULTS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usersTable>
    <employeeId>2</employeeId>
    <employeeName>Tom Williams                  </employeeName>
    <userPin>666666</userPin>
</usersTable>
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the API returns. JSON? XML? YAML? Plain text? Pandas? Koalas? Eucalyptus trees? Socks?

Comment: @DavidConrad I think it returns XML/JSON

Comment: You could simply curl the URL and find out what it's returning.

Comment: @DavidConrad I have used postman and it returns employee id, name and also pin. but I want to assign the pin to a variable

Comment: Yes, it returns them, but in what format? Why don't you edit your question and put the actual results from postman in it.

Comment: I have updated it @DavidConrad

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31015195/636009

Comment: here is what I received when I got the response from my app:            null{"type":"usersTable","employeeId":1,"employeeName":"Andrew Watson                 ","userPin":"123456"}

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [retrofit](https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-your-hand-dirty-with-retrofit-2-a-type-safe-http-client-for-android-and-java-c546f88b3a51) for android, because it will be easy to parse only only necessary values. For example, in my project I need to get user stats. For this, I create Model of values:

```
@SerializedName("user_stats")
@Expose
private List<MyStatsModel> myStats = null;
```

with **get** method

```
public List<MyStatsModel> getMyStats() {
    return myStats;
}
```

and easily make everithing I want with this values in my onResponse method:

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if(response.body().getMyStats() == null) {
                        emptyTextStats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        statsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("tag", "stats response null" + MainActivity.getSid());
                        emptyTextStats.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        statsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        statsAdapter.updateStats(response.body().getMyStats());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also, this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) will help you with parsing JSON to Model and java objects

Comment: I found retrofit quite confusing so I went with using the simple httpurlconnection

Comment: I agree with you, but retrofit is very useful technology, so, any case, you will have to learn it. But, may be later